# what is tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry" in android

Tags: android, xml

I have been learning google samples. In one of the source codes I cam across this code:

```
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:targetApi="o"
    tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry">
...
</layout>
```

**What tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry does?**

Answer (score 2):

> That means ignore the message about RtlSymmetry.

Android 4.1 (Jelly Bean) introduced limited support for bidirectional text in TextView and EditText elements, allowing apps to display and edit the text in both left-to-right (LTR) and right-to-left (RTL) scripts. Android 4.2 added full native support for RTL layouts, including layout mirroring, allowing you to deliver the same great app experience to all of your users, whether their language uses a script that reads right-to-left or one that reads left-to-right.

Answer (score 1):

It tells your IDE to ignore showing messages about padding (most likely) symmetry